# Posso substituir o termo "que é feito de" por cadê ou quedê sem prejuízo semântico?

Tags: etimologia, preposições, orações-subordinadas

Recentemente estava ouvindo a música [Amargurado](https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=XSqlUkWMMfI), dos compositores Tião Carreiro e Pardinho.

Logo no início, há o termo **que é feito de**, que, etimologicamente falando, significa *cadê*.

> O **que é feito d**aqueles beijos que eu te dei
>   Daquele amor cheio de ilusão
>   Que foi a razão do nosso querer
>   (...)

Ao escutar a canção, surgiram-me algumas dúvidas:

1. Posso substituir o termo grifado por *cadê*, *onde estão* ou *quedê* sem prejuízo semântico?
2. O uso da preposição *de* é obrigatório? Ex.: *O que é feito do bolo?* ou *O que é feito o bolo?*
3. No contexto apresentado, qual a função sintática do termo grifado¹?

<sup>Nota 1: Ao meu ver, o termo encaixa-se como uma *oração subordinada adverbial interrogativa*, porém encontrei nenhuma referência sobre esse tipo de oração.</sup>

Comment: fazer algo de algo não é cadé.

Comment: Através de uma pesquisa que fiz antes, *O que é feito de* ≠ ***D**o que é feito de*. O *cadê* vem da palavra *quede*/*quedê*, que deriva de *que é de*, que vem de *que é feito de*.

Answer (score 2):

Só posso responder parcialmente.

> 1. Posso substituir o termo grifado por *cadê*, *onde estão* ou *quedê* sem prejuízo semântico?

A substituição é possível em alguns casos, mas não sempre. Por exemplo, "o que é/foi feito de" pode também significar "**o que aconteceu com**", "**que fim levou**", como em "O que foi feito daquele monte de farinha que o Zé tinha comprado no ano passado?"

Mesmo quando a substituição é possível, aos meus ouvidos "o que é feito de" é mais pesado que "onde está": implica uma responsabilidade, ao sugerir que algo "é feito" e invoca mais fortemente a possibilidade do objeto da pergunta não mais existir.

> 2. O uso da preposição *de* é obrigatória? Ex.: *O que é feito do bolo?* ou *O que é feito o bolo?*

Sem o "de" a frase sequer me parece gramatical (qual seria o papel sintático de "o bolo"?), e, ainda que válido, omitir o "de" provavelmente alteraria seu significado.

Comment: "Só posso responder parcialmente", começou ele, respondendo de seguida a todos os pontos. :)

Comment: @ANeves  . #stafusa, pelo fato da expressão ter o verbo *é*, não seria, obrigatoriamente, considerado uma oração?

Comment: @ANeves :) Verdade, mas ainda considero parcial, porque respondi aos pontos 2 e 3 sem maior embasamento.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Bom ponto, na verdade estou convencido de que o termo de que você pergunta é parte da oração principal inclusive. Infelizmente minha análise sintática está enferrujada e estou com pouco tempo para pesquisar agora, então simplesmente apaguei a resposta ao item 3. :)

Comment: A justificativa é que fazer algo de algo não é fazer algo....a razão é semântica.